# ${}$Hawking radiation and Einstein-Cartan theory

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, big-bang, hawking-radiation, white-holes

As I understand it,  Einstein-Cartan theory predicts that inside every black hole, there is an einstein rosenbridge connecting to a new universe that forms due to a white hole.

Where does hawking radiation come into play? Ie, does hawking radiation act the  same? And if it does, what happens to the created universe once the black hole has fully irradiated?

What would it look like from the created universes perspective? Would mass be exiting the new universe to be transported outside the event horizon?

There are lots of similarities with this theory and the big bang, it gives a connection between the white hole  and the big bang, and gives a mathematical REASON that there is an expanding universe on the otherside of the black hole.

Could the universes expansion, specifically when the expansion of space is faster than light (ie we can never interact with it) be indicative of mass leaving our universe due to hawking radiation?

Comment: Any references for the statement in the first paragraph?

Comment: My understanding of this only comes from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Cartan_theory   under "avoidance of singularities" near the bottom

Comment: "The other side of the bridge becomes a new, growing baby universe. For observers in the baby universe, the parent universe appears as the only white hole." In https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole

Comment: After looking at those wiki pages, I feel obliged to point out that the "Avoidance of Singularities" section cites three papers by the same author as references, and nothing else.  The wiki account that wrote most of that section also wrote the section of the white hole page about EC theory, citing the same author.  In addition to a slew of edits adding discussion of EC theory to other pages, the same account also made edits to the page for the author of the references.  This doesn't mean anything is wrong, but caught my attention.

Comment: To my knowledge no one has worked out Hawking radiation in EC gravity.  While EC gravity is an active avenue of study, it's still pretty niche.  If you are interested in EC, your best bet is to dig into the papers.

Comment: Fig. 5 of Hawking's famous paper shows the Penrose diagram of an evaporating black hole. Maybe there's some way to glue the singularity there to a white hole of an eternal black/white hole Penrose diagram? Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any particular expertise in Einstein-Cartan theory, but I would caution against taking it seriously as describing real astronomical black holes. Even the simplest black hole solution, due to Schwarzschild, includes a time-symmetric white hole.  But it's not a solution for a black hole that forms by collapse; which is very time-asymmetric.  A Kerr black hole also is a theoretical solution that contains connection to other universes.  But that doesn't mean a rotating black hole formed from collapse of a star has that internal stucture.

Comment: Although regular GR may  not have formable  white hole solutions,  EC theory predicts this effect as a result of interactions at high densities, which is present is every blackhole

Answer (score -1):

You said: "As I understand it, Einstein-Cartan theory predicts that inside every black hole, there is an einstein rosenbridge connecting to a new universe that forms due to a white hole."

This statement is wrong. Read about [Einstein-Cartan theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Cartan_theory)  and [wormholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) .

You have asked:"Where does hawking radiation come into play? Ie, does hawking radiation act the same? "
[Hawking radition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) is commonly associated to the event horizon of any black hole. It's generalization for any theory of gravity is known as the [Wald eneropy](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9307038).

You have asked:"And if it does, what happens to the created universe once the black hole has fully irradiated?"
Your concern is right but only in the sence that the Hawking radiation leads to evaporation of the black hole and causes the [loss of information.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox)

With all due respect, I lost my apetite to read the rest of your post.

Comment: From the same Wikipedia page you quoted "In the Einstein–Cartan theory, instead, the collapse reaches a bounce and forms a regular Einstein–Rosen bridge (wormhole) to a new, growing universe on the other side of the event horizon.",  and your statement about hawking radiation doesn't really answer my question though, I guess no one has done the math with EC theory to answer my question

Comment: Notice that the Einstein-Hilbert theory is an example of the Einstein-Cartan theory. All solutions of the Einstein-Hilbert theory solve the Einstein-Cartan theory too. Some particular solutions in Cartan theory may avoid the singularity, but the singularity of the solutions of the Einstein-Hilbert theory is still present in the Cartan theory.